# How can a sidecar restart the app container or its own pod?

Tags: kubernetes, lifecycle, sidecar

I want to have a sidecar manage secret rotation, which requires the app container to restart in order to force it to pick up the updated credentials.

How can a sidecar force a container within the same pod to restart or the whole pod to restart?

Detailed explanation:

- Services of different tech stacks need to start using secrets. Secrets can either be injected via CI/CD or fetched at runtime from AWS Secrets Manager.
- Secrets need to be rotated every 3 months for security compliance reasons.
- Secrets are only used once at startup to create the related client. Since they are not used continuously, they are not naturally refreshed if updated at source storage.
- To minimise per-service development time, custom logic within each service to refresh the secrets should be avoided or minimised

Comment: how and when does the secret change?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to create new pods every 3 months? It would be a good thing from a security standpoint. You probably get new pods now and then anyway, when your nodes are upgraded, e.g. linux security patches.

Comment: how would you let the sidecar know that it should restart now? How would it know the secret has changed? I mean its pretty easy to use a sidecar to restart a pod, but you don't know when to do that. If you need to tell the sidecar somehow, then you might as well just restart the pod. Or do you intent to fetch the secret periodically with the sidecar? How do you deploy the pod in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There is a following pattern to rotate secrets without need to restart containers if you are running apps in EKS or ECS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/rotate-credentials-without-restarting-containers.html